# What would happen if I set more than the max amount of notifications from 2 different notification creations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

So on one page I have a function that creates 64 notifications for future times. On another view controller I have a calendar that will now set notifications for any holidays or events coming up in the next 30 days.

Being that I already maxed out my notifications previously, what happens if I try to add lets say 10 more (from 10 random holidays/events in that month)?

Answer (score 0):

The first 64 notifications that would fire are kept, and the rest are discarded.

> the system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications (with automatically rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and discards the rest.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification)

Comment: That's what I thought, but lets say I set 100 notifications in my first screen, none of them work. Only if I have 64 or less will the notification work.